# How to toggle two images to pause and play a game in SWIFT, SpriteKIT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to toggle between two images to pause and play my game. I tried using the code below but it doesn't work. I declared the pause and play as `SKSpriteNodes()`.

Can anyone help?

```
func paused(){
    self.scene?.view?.paused = true
    pause.removeFromParent() 
}

// PLAYING FUNCTION
func playing(){
    self.scene?.view?.paused = false
    play.removeFromParent()      
}
```

Comment: you aren't giving enough information. You remove `pause` and `play` from the scene but when do you add them back?

Answer (score 0):

*As someone else told you, you aren't giving enough informations for us to give you a precise answer.*

Anyway, the little part of your code that I can see doesn't seem to be right to me.

First of all you probably shouldn't use two nodes, nor delete any of them.
If your goal is simply to change the icon, you should use the same node and simply change its `texture` property.

*If you'd like an example, I can give you one.*

**EDIT : Here is the example**

```
// In this example, we will call playPauseNode the SKSpriteNode you are using as a button
var isPlaying = true

func buttonTouched() {
if isPlaying { // If the game is playing
playPauseNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "theNameOfYourPlayButtonImage")
isPlaying = false
}

else { // If the game is paused
playPauseNode.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "theNameOfYourPauseButtonImage")
isPlaying = true
}

}
```

I believe it should behave as you expect it to...

Comment: please do, i really need a help to finish off my game. thanks

Comment: I will when I'll be back at home ;)